# Jackson does not use custom Deserializer specified in class annotation

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

Jackson bean configured to use custom Deserializer

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = Planet.Deserializer.class)
public class Planet {

  static Map<String, Planet> SINGLETONS = Map.of(
          "EARTH", new Planet("Earth", 1),
          "MARS", new Planet("Mars", 2)
  );

  String name;
  // size is here to prevent Jackson from using the constructor
  int size;

  Planet(String name, int size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
  }

  static Planet valueOf(String name) {
    Planet planet = SINGLETONS.get(name);
    if (planet == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Planet by the name " + name + " found");
    }
    return planet;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static class Deserializer extends StdDeserializer<Planet> {

    public Deserializer() {
      super((Class<?>) null);
    }

    @Override
    public Planet deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
      final String value = jsonParser.getValueAsString();
      return Planet.valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
    }
  }
}
```

#### Planet works

```java
public class Expedition {
  Planet destination;
  public Planet getDestination() {
    return destination;
  }
  public void setDestination(Planet destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
  }
}
// custom deserializer is used
new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"destination\":\"mars\"}", Expedition.class)
```

#### List<Planet> works

```java
public class Expedition {
  List<Planet> list;
  public List<Planet> getList() {
    return this.list;
  }
  public void setList(List<Planet> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}
// custom deserializer is used
new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"list\":[\"mars\"]}", Expedition.class)
```

#### Map<Planet, String> does not work

```java
public class Expedition {
  private Map<Planet, String> map;
  public Map<Planet, String> getMap() {
    return this.map;
  }
  public void setMap(Map<Planet, String> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }
}
// custom deserializer is not used, invokes valueOf directly instead
new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"map\":{\"mars\" : \"a\"}}", Expedition.class)
```

Why isn't Jackson using the custom deserializer when the class is used as Map key ?

###### Solution for the issue:

I fixed the issue on my end by using`@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = ...)` in the Expedition class

**jackson-databind 2.15.2**